# Transform expression from Oracle to ssas

Tags: ssas, obiee

I have the following expression in oracle :

Cast ( Aggregate ("- Work Orders"."Estimation Difference" at "- Districts"."Districts dimension"."District", "- Work Group"."Work Group dimension"."Work Group Detail" ) as Double)

How to transform it to ssas ?

Comment: Is this a query or a reusable calculation? Do you already have an SSAS database with relationships built between your work orders fact and your district and work group dimensions? We need you to provide enough information that we can give you a good answer.

Comment: Your OBI column formula is just aggregating a measure at a certain dimensional level, where the dimensional levels are defined in the metadata repository. As @mmarie said, you haven't given any information about how this is defined in your RPD or how your data is set up on the database.